# Strange EF Core behaviour when setting navigation ID to null after upgrade to .NET 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

I'm going through the process of trying to upgrade from .NET 3.1 to .NET 6. I've managed to get everything building and upgraded various NuGet packages across my solution.

After trying to run my unit tests, I am encountering some strange problems with some EF operations. I am using the In-memory database provider for these unit tests.

I have a set-up similar to the following:

**Entities:**

```
public class EntityA
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? EntityBId { get; set; }
    public EntityB EntityB { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Configurations:**

```
public class EntityAConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<EntityA>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EntityA> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("EntitiyAs");

        builder.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnName("EntitiyAId")
            .IsRequired();
        
        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id)
            .HasName("PK_EntityAs");

        builder.HasIndex(e => e.EntityBId)
            .HasName("IX_EntityAs_EntityBId");

        builder.HasOne(e => e.EntityB)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.EntityBId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_EntityA_EntityBs_EntityBId");
    }
}

public class EntityBConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<EntityB>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EntityB> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("EntityBs");

        builder.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnName("EntityBId")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id)
            .HasName("PK_EntityBs");
    }
}
```

**Creating my test DBContext like this:**

```
private TestDbContext GenerateDbContext()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDbContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
        .Options;

    return new TestDbContext(options);
}
```

In my tests, I am pre-populating a few of these entities in the DbContext before executing the method I want to test. The method under test looks like this:

```
public async Task RemoveEntityBFromAssociatedEntityA(Guid entityBId)
{
    var entityB = await _dbContext.EntityBs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(g => g.Id == entityBId);
    if (entityB == null)
    {
        // throw exception...
    }

    var entityA = await _dbContext.EntityAs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.EntityBId == entityB);
    if (entityA == null)
    {
        // throw exception...
    }
    
    entityA.EntityBId = null;
    _dbContext.entityAs.Update(entityA);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

What I am doing here is removing the association to `EntityB` on `EntityA` by setting the navigation ID to null. Strangely, the effect this has is that `EntityA` is marked for deletion when it's `EntityBId` is set to null and when `SaveChanges` is called, it does infact delete `EntityA`.

This doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. Why would `EntityA` get deleted in this scenario? I've looked through the breaking changes in both EF Core 5 and EF Core 6 but I can't see anything that would cause this.

Comment: Does this also happen in the actual application? [You shouldn't use the in-memory database for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/#approach-3-the-ef-core-in-memory-database).

Comment: I also originally thought it might be an issue with using the in-memory provider but I tried switching it out for Sqlite and the same issue occurrs.

Comment: Then it looks like yet another bug in EF core 6. Please check the github issues if similar bugs have been reported.

Comment: I think this might actually be something to do with nullable reference types and how EF core handles this. I have nullable enabled in my project. Notice how the navigation property `EntityBId` in `EntityA` is a nullable Guid but the entity proprty is not nullable. I have just tried making this nullable as well (`public EntityB? EntityB { get; set; }`) and it _seems_ to have resolved the issue. Is this how we should be defining optional relationships when NRT is enabled now?

Comment: @AndyFurniss have you checked if the relationship is configred to be required and cascade? I think this might be the issue because the `EntityB` property is non nullable which results in a required relationship (which cascades by default) and therefore `EntityA` would cascade as soon as its relationship to `EntityB` is severed. Maybe try creating a migration and check if the model snapshot changes.

Comment: That explanation helped a lot @Nannanas. I've now succesfully finished upgrading!